# itemize inside multicolumn and tabularx

Tags: tabularx, itemize, multicolumn

How can I make the itemize fill the entire multicolumn as seen in the picture below?

I know my code might not be the most elegant solution, but I finished my entire document already and I'm very happy with the results, with this being the last problem I'm facing. Any help is highly appreciated.

[image: latex]

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\arrayrulecolor{blue}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{2pt}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{2pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{2pt}
\keepXColumns

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\color{blue}}>{\LARGE}Sr|S{X}>{\color{blue}}>{\large}Sr@{}}

Experience

& \large \textcolor{blue}{Intern} & Feb 2018–Aug 2018 \\
& \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X}{
{\large Company X} \newline
Department: Department X \newline
\begin{itemize}[nosep,leftmargin=*,before=\vspace{-\baselineskip},after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},label={\textcolor{blue}\textopenbullet}]
\item Management of procurement master data and processes for suppliers, commodities and buyers
\item Creation, consolidation and analysis of procurement data and reports
\end{itemize}}

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with a `p{...}` column, where the length is calculated by the `linegoal` package. I added a smallskip above the list, for aesthetic reasons. This package requires two compilations to compute the remaining space on the line.

Unrelated: note that when you load `ltablex`, you don't have to load `tabularx` nor `array`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\arrayrulecolor{blue}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{2pt}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{2pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{2pt}
\keepXColumns
\usepackage{linegoal}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\color{blue}}>{\LARGE}Sr|S{X}>{\color{blue}}>{\large}Sr@{}}
Experience
& \large \textcolor{blue}{Intern} & Feb 2018–Aug 2018 \\
& \multicolumn{2}{p{\linegoal}@{}}{%
{\large Company X} \newline
Department: Department X \smallskip\newline
\begin{itemize}[nosep, leftmargin=*, before=\vspace{-\baselineskip}, after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}, label={\textcolor{blue}\textopenbullet}]
\item Management of procurement master data and processes for suppliers, commodities and buyers
\item Creation, consolidation and analysis of procurement data and reports
\end{itemize}}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for the tips, too. Do you have any idea how to get rid of that new blank space that appeared now (between "Intern" and "Company X")? I know I can do something like `\\[-10pt]` but I wonder why it appeared in the first place.

Comment: Okay just changing `p` to `b` does the trick...

Comment: @Nico: I've just discovered you comment about the blank space. I had=n't even noticed it as the difference in colours seemed to require  some vertical spacing. Another solution would have been to use `\\[-2ex]` at the end of the row (or some other value at your convenience).